# Open another form from hyperlink text in RichTextBox in Ms Access form instead using button click

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink, richtextbox

I need to open another form or call MessageBox from hyperlink text or a button that is in a RichTextBox control in my Ms Access Application form. Is it possible, if yes, what do I this work?

Comment: Never heard of a button in a RichTextBox. How could that be possible? Why is a RichTextBox control involved? Are you using Hyperlink type field? Review http://allenbrowne.com/casu-09.html. Or constructing hyperlink string with expression?

Comment: Is it possible to convert  one of the word in Richtextbox to a hyperlink to show a message box by click on it?

Comment: Textbox has Click event, text within that box does not. No, text within text is not clickable. It can be formatted to look like hyperlink but code would be in textbox Click event.